# Access flask application running on home server from another network (nginx/gunicorn)

Tags: nginx, flask, gunicorn

I'm having a bit of an issue accessing my nginx/gunicorn webapp server from outside of my local network. I'm not entirely sure what's wrong with my configuration, but I've spent hours on trial and error based on similar questions asked on stackoverflow with no success.

Here is my nginx configuration:

```
server {
        listen *:80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name _;

        location /static {
                alias /home/pi/wl_app/wl_/website/static;
        }

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
                include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }

}
```

And here is the configuration for supervisor, which runs gunicorn:

```
[program:wl_app]
directory=/home/pi/wl_app/wl_
command=/home/pi/wl_app/wl_/lift-venv/bin/gunicorn -w 9 main:app -b 0.0.0.0:8000
autostart=true
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/wl_app/wl_app.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/wl_app/wl_app.out.log
```

My firewall is currently turned off and my ISP is not blocking the port I'm trying to use. Please let me know if there is any helpful information I can provide.

To be clear, the application works fine on my mobile device when I'm connected to the same network through wifi, but I cannot access the site if I switch to mobile data.

Thanks in advance for any hints anyone may be able to provide.

Comment: Assuming your home network hands out DHCP addresses from a router, you'll need to give that particular server a static IP address and then arrange to 'port forward' through the router. The details of doing those depend in large part on the router. There are plenty of tutorials online, though. Search for "port forward through {{router}}", inserting your router model.

Comment: @DaveW.Smith Thanks for your response! I have set up port forwarding through my router to the internal IP of the device I am using as my server, with the external port set to 8000. I guess where this falls apart for me is making sure the server runs on a static IP address. Is this achieved through making sure the app is run on localhost whenever it spins up? Forgive me if this is ignorant, I'm still very new to network stuff like this.

Comment: Since you have nginx running, route to port 80. Static IP is a machine config thing, completely separate from applications. The IP you choose has to be one that the router is O.K. with. Minimally, that'll be outside the range of DHCP addresses the router hands out.

Comment: I have tried several different configurations w/r/t setting the server's IP to static. Between trying a handful of different IPs and ensuring that my port forwarding is set to 80, I am still having trouble communicating with the server outside of its local network. My router fixes the IP address to a particular client by way of what they call "Address Reservation" and all of the addresses seem to match up between what I set to static in my server and what is reserved through the router.

Comment: Major update/slap on the forehead. After connecting to my *public* IP address, everything works like a charm. Thanks for the advice, as your recommended IP configurations were necessary as well. This is what I get for troubleshooting network stuff so late at night. Will probably kill this question in the morning. Thanks again!